# Using i2cssh with highSierra

Tags: high-sierra, ssh, iterm

I have the latest `i2cssh` installed

`dmanna-a01:Downloads dmanna$ brew info i2cssh
i2cssh: stable 1.3, HEAD
https://github.com/djui/i2cssh
/usr/local/Cellar/i2cssh/1.3 (5 files, 6.5KB) *
  Built from source on 2018-06-04 at 16:11:43
From: /usr/local/opt/i2cssh/.brew/i2cssh.rb
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version`

But whenever I try to ssh to multiple machines like below:-

`i2cssh -Xi=/tmp1/vnera-infra-ec2.pem -l support -b -d row -m "10.153.190.196,10.153.189.27,10.153.189.220"`

This does not seem to work and just opens the multiple terminals without the `ssh` prompt

[image]

The above command worked perfectly in Mac Sierra.

Versions

- Iterm2 - 3.1.6
- Mac OS - 10.13.4

Can someone let me know what is going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Can you ssh into one host? With or without the i2c prepended ?

Comment: If I just do `ssh support@ip` it is working fine. The above `i2cssh` command used to work fine in Sierra.

Comment: I was hoping to get you to simplify this like `i2cssh -Xi=/tmp1/vnera-infra-ec2.pem -l support -b -d row -m "10.153.190.196"` but that's fine - it's your question to ask. You'lllikely be getting either a RTFM on debugging certificates and i2cssh or perhaps someone has a workaround that's undocumented or can point to the changes.